# Chunksize not giving expected output

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My dataset has about 3 million rows which made loading it using jupyter notebook really slow. So I tried using 'chunksize' and I have pasted the code below but but its printing nothing at all.

This is my code:

```
chunksize = 1000000
for chunk in pd.read_csv('US_Accidents_Dec19.csv',  iterator=True, chunksize=chunksize):
    chunk.head()
```

When I made the following changes:

```
chunksize = 1000000
for chunk in pd.read_csv('US_Accidents_Dec19.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=chunksize):
   data=chunk
data.head()
```

It printed only the first 5 rows.

Comment: You should first try reading [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's not clear in what's the problem? What is the expected output? what is the current output / error ?

Comment: Looks like you are replacing `data` each time in your loop instead of appending to it.

Comment: You asked for 5 rows with `data.head()` and declare having 5 rows. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, `data.head()` is requesting just the top 5 rows in `data`, which has yielded the behavior you observed. `data` itself will hold 1,000,000 rows in each iteration except the last one, where it will have the remainder of the file which may be a little less. You can confirm that by printing `data.shape` instead of `data.head()`.

Also, since you're doing that at the end of your iteration through the chunks, that will end up being rows 2,000,001 through 2,000,005 of your file. If you truly want to work on the whole file in chunks, you'll need to do your processing inside the loop. If all you want is to use a sample from your file, you can instead use `pd.read_csv(..., nrows=10000)` to read only the top 10k rows.